# Creating a star shape implementing Icon and display in JOptionPane

Tags: java

Below is the assignment I was given:

> Write a class that implements the icon interface and draw a star using
>   given coordinates. Display the star in a JOption Pane
>
> - coordinates: (100,10) (125,75) (200,85) (150,125) (160,190) (100,150) (40,190) (50,125) (0,85) (75,75)
> - set the width and height of the icon to 200x200
> - set the line color to blue

I have found that I need an Icon tester but don't know where to go from the point I have gotten to so far. Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import javax.swing.Icon;

public class Star implements Icon {
    public StarIcon(){

    }
    public int getStarHeight(){
        return 200;
    }
    public int getStarWidth(){
        return 200;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y){
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(100, 10, 125, 75);
        g.drawLine(125, 75, 200, 85);
        g.drawLine(200, 85, 150, 125);
        g.drawLine(150, 125, 160, 190);
        g.drawLine(160, 190, 100, 150);
        g.drawLine(100, 150, 40, 190);
        g.drawLine(40, 190, 50, 125);
        g.drawLine(50, 125, 0, 85);
        g.drawLine(0, 85, 75, 75);
        g.drawLine(75, 75, 100, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem. I see the assignment, I see your code... I don't see where you tell us what about the current code is not working for you.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is some frame-application that displays the icon? Create a simple JFrame, add a JLabel and set the icon for the JLabel (`myJLabel.setIcon(new Star());` something like this?)

Comment: i don't understand what the icon tester needs to look like and when i compile in eclipse it gives me a bunch various errors (dispatch, eventqueue) and therefore doesnt show the star shape